# Transcription from phonetic form to pronunciation

Tags: java, android

this is my first question here, please don't be cruel :).

I am creating dictionary application for Android. I have source dictionary ([LMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_Markup_Framework)) which contains data including pronunciation. 
For example I have

```
    word: "transcription"
    phoneticForm: "trHn'skrIpSEn"
```

My question is: How do I get something like this "trænˈskrɪpʃ(ə)n"?
Is there any library for transcription?

Thank you for any response which can guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something to translate X-SAMPA (which phoneticForm looks like) to IPA? If so, [this page has code for doing so in several programming languages](http://www.theiling.de/ipa/). Unfortunately none of them are Java, but if you know one of Perl, Python, C++ or Lisp you may be able to adapt that code into Java.

Comment: Yes after some time of googling I found that notation of pronunciation what we all know is called IPA and representation in ASCII (and in LMF) is called X-SAMPA but I was not able to found any library.

I have not said that I transform LMF to sqlite in python script, so your answer is the best :) 
I will test this library and tell how good it is and after that I will mark your answer as accepted. Did you use that library for some project?

Comment: So I tried that library, made some changes to make it compatible with python3, and it works. But not so great with my data, I think. For example: zaibatsu, my SAMPA form: 'zaIbHt'su: IPA: from script: 'zaIbHt'su: and correct form: [/ˈzaɪbɑˈtsu/](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zaibatsu) I don't know what is good and what is wrong..

Comment: I found online [converter](http://www.lfsag.unito.it/ipa/converter_en.html) for testing and when I put to IPA  ˈzaɪbɑˈtsu I get "zaIbA"tsu at SAMPA. In my document as I said is 'zaIbHt'su: Maybe just my data are wrong.